# How to resize ALL tables in a LyX document of tables?

Tags: lyx-layouts

I am using another piece of software (STATA) to generate the tex code for my statistical tables. I am also using a LyX document with many Child documents to display all the tables in the one document. The tables are based on the `booktabs` package. I have

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

in my preamble followed by the code generated by STATA.

To resize each table, I need to insert the following code in the appropriate place: 
`\resizebox{14cm}{!} { \begin{tabular}... \end{tabular} }`. Each individual table is fitted into the 14cm width and the table contents are scaled accordingly and the process is working well.

However, instead of manually inserting  the same `\resizebox{14cm}{!} { ... }` EVERY TIME I produce a new version of the table, how can I automate resizing ALL tables in the LyX document regardless of when they were produced? What else could I add to the preamble to make this happen? I am still quite new to LaTeX and LyX.

Here is some sample code of what I am doing:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{My TABLE TITLE}

\resizebox{14cm}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
\toprule
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 4}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 5}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 6}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 7}\\
\midrule
lat         &     -0.0160\sym{***}&    -0.00729\sym{***}&    -0.00716\sym{***}&    -0.00736\sym{***}&    -0.00708\sym{***}&    -0.00728\sym{***}&    -0.00714\sym{***}\\
            &    (-73.62)         &    (-13.10)         &    (-12.72)         &    (-13.08)         &    (-12.65)         &    (-13.03)         &    (-13.12)         \\
levratio    &      0.0142\sym{***}&      0.0368\sym{***}&      0.0366\sym{***}&      0.0368\sym{***}&      0.0366\sym{***}&      0.0367\sym{***}&      0.0369\sym{***}\\
            &     (10.13)         &     (14.74)         &     (14.68)         &     (14.72)         &     (14.68)         &     (14.70)         &     (14.76)         \\
roa         &     -0.0204\sym{***}&      -0.121\sym{***}&      -0.121\sym{***}&      -0.121\sym{***}&      -0.121\sym{***}&      -0.120\sym{***}&      -0.121\sym{***}\\
            &    (-14.83)         &    (-20.08)         &    (-20.11)         &    (-20.03)         &    (-20.11)         &    (-20.00)         &    (-20.09)         \\
intcovratio & -0.00000100\sym{***}&  0.00000716         &  0.00000735         &  0.00000724         &  0.00000738         &  0.00000734         &  0.00000743         \\
            &     (-3.40)         &      (1.24)         &      (1.27)         &      (1.25)         &      (1.28)         &      (1.27)         &      (1.29)         \\
spindx      &  -0.0000140         & -0.00000683         & -0.00000705         & -0.00000698         & -0.00000705         & -0.00000718         & -0.00000702         \\
            &     (-1.63)         &     (-0.49)         &     (-0.51)         &     (-0.51)         &     (-0.51)         &     (-0.52)         &     (-0.51)         \\
rating      &                     &    -0.00211\sym{***}&    -0.00218\sym{***}&    -0.00210\sym{***}&    -0.00219\sym{***}&    -0.00208\sym{***}&    -0.00212\sym{***}\\
            &                     &    (-14.65)         &    (-14.36)         &    (-14.56)         &    (-14.57)         &    (-14.08)         &    (-14.45)         \\
al5yr       &                     &    0.000284\sym{+}  &   -0.000395         &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
            &                     &      (1.86)         &     (-0.81)         &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
ratXal5yr   &                     &                     &   0.0000393         &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
            &                     &                     &      (1.47)         &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
sa5yr       &                     &                     &                     &    0.000107         &   -0.000744         &                     &                     \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.46)         &     (-1.29)         &                     &                     \\
jv5yr       &                     &                     &                     &     0.00133         &                     &     0.00219         &                     \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (1.26)         &                     &      (0.74)         &                     \\
lic5yr      &                     &                     &                     &    0.000779         &                     &                     &    0.000750         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &      (0.86)         &                     &                     &      (0.39)         \\
ratXsa5yr   &                     &                     &                     &                     &   0.0000606\sym{+}  &                     &                     \\
            &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (1.90)         &                     &                     \\
ratXjv5yr   &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &  -0.0000328         &                     \\
            &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.18)         &                     \\
ratXlic5yr  &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &   0.0000266         \\
            &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.25)         \\
\_cons      &       0.218\sym{***}&       0.172\sym{***}&       0.173\sym{***}&       0.172\sym{***}&       0.172\sym{***}&       0.172\sym{***}&       0.171\sym{***}\\
            &     (16.95)         &      (8.12)         &      (8.13)         &      (8.11)         &      (8.11)         &      (8.12)         &      (8.06)         \\
\midrule
\(N\)       &       34559         &        8675         &        8675         &        8675         &        8675         &        8675         &        8675         \\
\(R^{2}\)   &       0.217         &       0.297         &       0.297         &       0.297         &       0.297         &       0.297         &       0.297         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize ...}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize ...}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize  ...}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize  ...}\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize ...}\\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Really more of a Stata question than a TeX one, but it looks like there's a `topf` and a `botf` option for tables. See [Publication quality tables in Stata: a tutorial for the tabout program](http://www.ianwatson.com.au/stata/tabout_tutorial.pdf), particularly p.33.

Comment: I "solved" my problem by adding in the preamble 
\let\oldtabular\tabular \renewcommand{\tabular}{\footnotesize\oldtabular}
Not an ideal solution, but it makes my tables all fit in the table width. 

I looked Mike Renfro's suggestion, but that is specific to Stata. I was hoping for a TeX solution.